# Remove a certain line from Bash history file

Tags: linux, bash, history, command-history

How can I remove a certain line from `history`'s database?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You need to log out and back in or run `history -a` so the current history is committed to disk.

Then just edit the file `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: If the HISTFILE environment variable is set, the history file isn't ~/.bash_history but rather ${HISTFILE}.

Comment: Entries are written into the history file when you exit the shell. Therefore, after entering a command that you'd like to remove, you need to either log out and back in, or use 'history -d xxxx' to remove them from the current shell session.

Comment: but how would you delete the record of editing the history file?

Comment: @chiliNUT: Just start your command (e.g. `vim ~/.bash_history`) with a space; commands starting with a space usually don't get logged (see `$HISTCONTROL`).

Comment: I don't think thats the case in my distribution, but in general that makes sense

Comment: Using `sed` for doing this, instead of an *handy editor* ensure **all** occurence will be dropped! See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/621767/178656)

Comment: To hide commands starting with a space (and also hide duplicate entries) from your bash history, put this in your .bashrc `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth`

Comment: `history -d` seems like a more correct approach.

Comment: `history -a` first is what most other answers about this are missing, thank you.

Answer (score 162):

You can achieve removal from the history file using the commandline in two steps:

1. Typing `history -d <line_number>` deletes a specified line from the history in memory.
2. Typing `history -w` writes the current in-memory history to the `~/.bash_history` file.

The two steps together remove the line permanently from the in-memory *history* and from the *.bash_history* file as well.

Comment: how to delete the last `history -w` from history?

Comment: @KrIsHnA edit ~/.bash_history manually

Comment: Or add a space before it to prevent it from being added, as in @tao's answer

Comment: To find `<line_number>` just `history | grep [unwanted_content]` to get a list with all the lines containing `[unwanted_content]` (like passwords).

Comment: How do you delete multiple (specific) lines (by id) ?

Comment: You saved me and my bash history

Comment: this won’t work if `$PROMPT_COMMAND` contains `history -a`. unset that environment variable and try again if you see that the deleted lines are not deleted in fact.

Comment: If you ``grep`` for the thing you want to remove you've probably just added to the history again.  If it was recent you can just run ``history | tail``.

Answer (score 43):

To *prevent* a command from being added to the history in the first place, make sure that the environment variable `HISTCONTROL` contains among its colon-separated values the value `ignorespace`, for example (add e.g. to `.bashrc`):

```
$ export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

This will prevent any command with a leading space from being added to the history. You can then clear the history completely by running

```
$  history -c -w
  ^-- additional space character
```

Answer (score 37):

First of all, if the command you're about to issue is sensitive, unsafe, or you just don't need it cluttering up your history, it is best/quickest to just prevent it from entering the history in the first place. Make sure that `$HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace`:

```
(bash)$ echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoredups:ignorespace
```

Then proceed any command you don't want in your history with a space:

```
(bash)$  sensitive-cmd-with --password 82cf7dfe
(bash)$  rm -r... # One-off recursive remove; mustn't be accidentally repeated!
```

If you accidentally put an unwanted command into history, providing that your bash session is still open, the command hasn't yet touched the disk. To delete the previous command in history, issue:

```
(bash)$  history -d $((HISTCMD-1))
```

*Note the leading space; this command requires `ignorespace`, otherwise it'll just delete itself!*

If you want to delete the last few commands, find the last and first history number:

```
(bash)$  history 5
  598  ok
  599  sensitive
  600  unsafe
  601  doesn\'t-work
  602  otherwise-unwanted
```

In this case 602 and 599. Then issue:

```
(bash)$  for i in {602..599}; do history -d $i; done
```

*(Without `ignorespace`, it would be 603..599.)*

If you don't want *any* history from your current session to hit the disk, exit using:

```
(bash)$ kill -9 $$
```

The approach so far is to not even let sensitive history items be written to disk for extra security, because in theory data deleted from non-volatile media can still be recovered.

If, however, the command(s) you wish to remove are from a previous session, they will have already been appended to the `$HISTFILE` on exit. Manipulating the history with the above commands will still only *append* the remaining *new* items to the `$HISTFILE`, *on exit*. To *overwrite* the `$HISTFILE` with the current session's view of the *entire* history, *right now*, issue:

```
(bash)$  history -w
```

Of course for history items already on disk, the alternative to editing the history with `history -d` commands then issuing `history -w`, is to edit the `$HISTFILE` with a text editor.

Comment: ”Manipulating the history with the above commands will still only _append_ the remaining _new_ items to the `$HISTFILE`, _on exit_.” Actually, this isn't exactly true. It seems to only append remaining new items that ‘stick out’ from the original history length. E.g. If I remove 5 original items and add 15 new, only the last 10 new are appended, whereas I'd expect all 15 new to be appended. I think this is a bug because I can't see how this is ever desirable functionality.

Comment: I guess bash takes note of the original length. On session close, it presumably appends items whose number is greater than this value. If this value was decremented every time an item is deleted whose number is less than or equal to this value, it would work as expected. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Several techniques:

#### Prevent sensitive information from being stored in the history file

If you've entered some password on a command line, then realize that all commands are logged, you could either:

1. Force exit the current session without saving history:

   ```
    kill -9 $$
   ```

   This will drop all current history.

   1. As correctly pointed out by [S0AndS0'comment](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/2830852?noredirect=1), another way is to modify *history file name*:

      ```
      HISTFILE=
      ```
2. Type <kbd>↑ (up arrow)</kbd> in the open bash session until the sensitive information is shown, then use line editing keystrokes like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to delete the sensitive info, and **then** <kbd>↓ (down arrow)</kbd> until a new empty line is prompted, **before** typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Delete sensitive information from the history file

If you realize that sensitive information is already stored, and you want to delete it, but not your entire history:

A simple `sed` command could do the job:

```
sed -e '/SeNsItIvE InFo/d' -i .bash_history
```

but, as you type this, you create another history line containing the search pattern (sensitive info) you are trying to delete. So you could:

```
sed -e "/$(head -n1)/d" -i .bash_history
```

This will run `head -n1` with input from the terminal.
It will appear that your terminal is hung (there won't be a prompt);
just type the information that you want to delete from the file.
This is a trick to let you enter (part of) a command
without actually typing it into the command line,
thus making it ineligible for inclusion in the history record.
Then `sed` will use the text that you typed to search `.bash_history`
and delete all lines containing the sensitive info.
Note: if your sensitive information pattern contains slash(es),
you must escape them with backslashes,
or else change the `sed` command to use this syntax
to specify a delimiter that does not appear in the pattern:

```
sed -e "\|$(head -n1)|d" -i .bash_history
```

Another way could be to delete only the sensitive info, but keep the commands that contain the information. For this, you could simply replace sensitive info with substitute text of your choice:

```
sed -e "s/$(head -n1)/Santa Claus/g" -i .bash_history.
```

#### Delete sensitive information from any file in a specific tree

Finally, to be sure that this won't stay in *another* forgotten file:

```
SENSITIVEINFO="$(head -n1)"
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "$SENSITIVEINFO"
```

will list all concerned files.

```
find . -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 grep -lZ "$SENSITIVEINFO" |
    xargs -0 sed -e "s/$SENSITIVEINFO/Santa Claus/g" -i
```

will replace all occurrences of sensitive info in all files
in the directory tree rooted at `.`.
Note: even though this command uses `xargs -0`,
it will not handle files with newlines in their names.

Comment: Combining tricks from a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37319056/2632107) it should be possible to delete `SeNsItIvE InFo` and the `sed` command doing the deletion on the same line with something like `sed -e '/SeNsItIvE InFo/d' -i .bash_history; history -d $((HISTCMD-1))`

Comment: You don't need ``kill -9 $$`` to exit with out saving the history.  Just run ``HISTFILE=``.  Then when you exit the history is not saved.

Comment: @jcoffland You're right! But which one are more simpler / intuitive ?? Anyway, I've edited my answer to add your purpose...

Answer (score 14):

Locate the line you want to delete by pressing <kbd>↑ (up arrow)</kbd> until it appears, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. That should remove the line.

If you use the `history` command, you can see the line has been substituted with an asterisk.

Comment: Actually, I believe that you must cursor up to the line, press Ctrl+U, _and then cursor up or down to another line_ (possibly the blank one at the bottom of the list).  Also, strictly speaking, the line hasn't been substituted with an asterisk.  Rather, the command has been erased, and the _history number_ has been appended with a `*`.

Comment: This becomes much more powerful with Ctrl+R (reverse incremental history search), then e.g. [End], Ctrl+U

Answer (score 5):

If you need to remove several lines at the same time I normally use this:

```
history | grep <string> | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | awk '{print "history -d " $1}'
```

If you need to remove the last command you can use:

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-2))
```

Comment: This looked like it worked but `history | grep <string>` still shows all the lines it claimed to delete...

Comment: This will delete the wrong history lines after deleting the fisrt!!

Comment: But fortunately, it only prints the wrong delete commands. The following would print the correct delete commands: `history | grep XYZ | grep -v grep | tac | awk '{print "history -d", $1}'`

Answer (score 4):

If you need to remove a range of lines from history, the following bash function could save you some time:

```
function histdel() {
    [ $# -eq 1 ] && history -d "$1" && history -w
    if [ $# -eq 2 -a "$1" -le "$2" ]; then
        for n in `seq "$2" "$1"`; do
            history -d "$n"
        done
        history -w
    fi
}
```

Function should be typically added to `$HOME/.bashrc`. To use the function imediatelly, you will need to have the file read again by your running shell (`. $HOME/.bashrc`). Then to delete e.g. commands 200-210 from history:

```
$ histdel 200 210
```

(Note: This question is among the top search results if you search for deleting a range of commands from bash history. So, while the above is more than what the question asks, it could be useful for some readers.)

Comment: Alternative forms for the `for` statement: `for n in $(seq "$2" "$1")` is stylistically preferred by some, and, if `seq` doesn’t work, try `for ((n="$2"; n>="$1"; n--))`.

Comment: couldn't get this to work - although the premise of using bashrc functions as integrated user-space commands was fun to play with.

Answer (score 3):

```
history | sed -i 59d
```

59 is the line number. Cannot be anything sweeter than this :)

Answer (score 3):

Just try these,

```
$ history
```

this will display the id of the history and the command, e.g.

> .
>   .
>   211 ls
>   212 javac Welcome.java
>   213 java welcome
>   .
>   .

use,

```
$ history -d 211
```

Here 211 is the id of the history. Now check this using

```
$ history
```

> .
>   .
>   211 javac Welcome.java
>   212 java welcome
>   .
>   .

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a long time since this question has been asked and answered but I'll show you my method for cleaning my history file and logging out at the same time.

I run :
`history -w && nano "${HISTFILE}" && history -c && exit`

What it does is simple:

1. `history -w` : writes cached history inside `"${HISTFILE}"`
2. `nano "${HISTFILE}"` : allow me to edit `"${HISTFILE}"` You could use a sed script or whatever your want to clean your `"${HISTFILE}"`
3. `history -c` : clear cached history so this last command is not appended.
4. `exit` : log me out appending cached history... but it is empty ;)

After that command, you'll be logged out with a clean history file.
Log in to check your history ;)

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could also edit the history file directly, eg `nano .bash_history` if you are in the bash shell?