# ZSH / BASH : Delete specific lines from history

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, history

My history is 'polluted' with some specific lines that have typo's and such. For example: I often have to ssh to a certain server like so:

```
ssh foo-bar@domain.tld
> Connects succesfully
```

But I also make a typo sometimes:

```
ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> Permission denied
```

Because I rely on history this typo is duplicated multiple times:

```
cat .zsh_history | grep bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1510301683:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1511166682:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1511193552:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1512730972:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1516368993:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1516802690:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
> : 1519633368:0;ssh bar-foo@domain.tld
```

Is there an easy way to clean up my history purely by the results of the `grep`-command? (or perhaps there's some other, more clever solution?)

*Update:*

Please note: I am not looking for a way to delete line `x` from the history; I know there are plenty of articles out there that cover that. I'm simply looking for a (simple?) way to delete all lines that contain string `y`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a certain line from Bash history file](https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file)

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate. I just want to clean my history by deleting all lines that contain string `x`. The linked question is how to delete by line numbers.

Comment: You might be interested in zsh's option **HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS** in order to not stor duplicates in your history at all: If a new command line being added to the history list duplicates an older one, the older command is  removed from the list (even if it is not the previous event).

Comment: @GielBerkers, [Remove a certain line from Bash history file](https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file) seems quite general, with answers using various methods.  The simplest `grep` fix is in a [comment by *mivk](https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file#comment878325_529193), which prints out the needed commands, (without actually running them): `history | grep XYZ | grep -v grep | tac | awk '{print "history -d", $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

This function will remove any one line you want from your Zsh history, no questions asked:

```sh
# Accepts one history line number as argument.
# Alternatively, you can do `dc -1` to remove the last line.
dc () {
  # Prevent the specified history line from being saved.
  local HISTORY_IGNORE="${(b)$(fc -ln $1 $1)}"

  # Write out the history to file, excluding lines that match `$HISTORY_IGNORE`.
  fc -W

  # Dispose of the current history and read the new history from file.
  fc -p $HISTFILE $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST

  # TA-DA!
  print "Deleted '$HISTORY_IGNORE' from history."
}
```

If you want to additionally prevent all `dc` commands from being written to history, add the following in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
zshaddhistory() {
 [[ $1 != 'dc '* ]]
}
```

---

Alternatively, for a more comprehensive solution, try my [Zsh Edit plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist).

Comment: @GielBerkers Does this answer your question/solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to delete properly all lines with the string in the history :

```
sed -i '/string/d' .bash_history
```