# Clear display of specfic command

Tags: bash, terminal

Can you clear the output of specific past commands ? For example, 3 commands ago you did a CAT on a large file and now its content is useless, can you clear it to see only the previous commands ? clear would delete everything so it's not appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a certain line from Bash history file](https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file)

Comment: I don't think so, I want to clear the display of this command, not just remove entries in the history